# Alternative to for loop to populate ddl with static items

Tags: c#, for-loop, .net-4.0

I've used the term 'static' here in the sense that I know what the items will always be.

I have a drop-down list, and in the drop down list I want to populate it with a list of groups (85 groups) so the items will be as follows:

```
"Group 1"
"Group 2"
"Group 3"
```

etc.

What I've Got So Far

```
for (int i = 0; i < 85; i++)
{
  ddlGroups.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "Group " + (i+1) } );
}
```

Is there an alternative way to achieve this? Maybe an approach using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ example:

```
ddlGroups.Items.AddRange(Enumerable
    .Range(0, 85)
    .Select(i => new ListItem() { Text = "Group " + (i + 1)} );
```